# Want to extract pinned messages from the groups/channels on Telegram i am part of using Telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm using Telethon API
Want to extract pinned messages of all the channels i am member.
Please guide me with the procedure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetFullChannelRequest` and `GetHistoryRequest` methods to extract pinned message from one channel

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel

api_id = XXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+98XXXXXXXX'
################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash
                    )

assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

channel_entity = client.get_entity(PeerChannel(channel_id))

channel_info = client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel_entity))

pinned_msg_id = channel_info.full_chat.pinned_msg_id

if pinned_msg_id is not None:
    posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
        channel_entity,
        limit=1,
        offset_date=None,
        offset_id=pinned_msg_id + 1,
        max_id=0,
        min_id=0,
        add_offset=0,
        hash=0
    ))
    print(posts.messages[0].to_dict())
```

I used `Telethon V0.19`, but the previous versions are pretty much the same

Comment: Thank you so much, Brother. Your code was really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As of Telethon 1.2, the code is a lot simpler:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, types, sync
with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    message = client.get_messages('TelethonChat', ids=types.InputMessagePinned())
```

This won't work for private chats, however (e.g. to fetch the pinned message with yourself). For that, as the currently accepted answer hints, we have to fetch the `Full` object. For the case of the private chat, this is [`UserFull`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/user_full.html) by using [`GetFullUserRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/users/get_full_user.html):

```
chat = 'me'
full = client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(chat))
message = client.get_messages(chat, ids=full.pinned_msg_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all pinned messages from channel using `Telethon 1.19.5` (sync version) and above you can

```py
from telethon.tl.types import InputMessagesFilterPinned
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync  # noqa: F401

channel_id = -1009999999999

with TelegramClient("name", api_id, api_hash) as client:
    # we need to set limit
    # because otherwise it will return only first pinned message
    pinned_messages = client.get_messages(
        channel_id,
        filter=InputMessagesFilterPinned,
        limit=1000,
    )
    for message in pinned_messages:
        print(message.message)
```